# ng-if condition always fails

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS

```
 <div ng-repeat="l in kites">
    <a ng-click="findit(l.green.num)">color</a>
   <span ng-if="c_{{l.green.num}} == 'y'>kites is </span>
    </div>
```

In my controller I have

```
$scope.cnt=[];
$scope.findit = function(c){
$scope.cnt.push(c);
    angular.forEach($scope.cnt, function(value, key){
        $scope['c_'+value] = 'y' ;

    })
}
```

My problem is, I'm not getting the span value even the conditions falls true.. 
means while `l.green.num` is 5 , `c_5 ='y'`. But it is not accepted in the if condition. Please help me.

Comment: Can you share same using jsfiddle

Comment: There is a  `"` missing in your `ng-if` in your `span` !!

Comment: where is php? question tagged with `php`

Comment: $scope is not an array. Did you mean $scope.cnt['c_'+value] = 'y' ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2nxwaonv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your solution:

```js
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
 $scope.kites = [{
   'green':{
     'num':1
    }
  }]
  $scope.cnt = [];
  $scope.findit = function(c) {
    $scope.cnt.push(c);
    angular.forEach($scope.cnt, function(value, key) {
      $scope['c_' + value] = 'y';

    })
  }

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="l in kites">
    <a ng-click="findit(l.green.num)">color</a>
    <span ng-show="{{'c_'+l.green.num}} == 'y'">kites is </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do up vote as it motivates us to contribute more on stack overflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use brackets in ng-if conditions. This won't interpolate the value before evaluation.

What you could do is adding a "selected" value to your kite when clicked.
Example :

**Controller**

```
$scope.findit = function(c){
    c.selected = true;   
}
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="l in kites">
    <a ng-click="findit(l.green)">color</a>
   <span ng-if="l.green.selected">kites is </span>
</div>
```